# Putting up my new ceiling fan into light fixture

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan, installation

I have 4 ceiling fans I ordered to put these up into 4 light fixture. This one is a bit different that I did put up into replace an old ceiling fan and it was easy for me.

I am not experience with the light fixture because it is different than the ceiling fan.

I have three pictures to attach for you all to look at. I am not entire sure if this is the proper way to install.

Before I started to remove it the picture looks like this [image]

So after this I remove this to check what is behind the light so I can know what I need to buy to support the ceiling fan (Yes I did google but it lacks answer my questions). What I found is I have a wood that is behind the light.

Look at the picture here [image]

So I remove the black plastic bracket and install this [image]and then this [image] and it looks like this [image]

My only question is would that be ok if I put up the ceiling fan even if the mental bracket ceiling fan box is under the wall ?

My gut feeling is maybe should I just take out the Ceiling Fan Box with Metal Cover and just leave the Fan Master Jr. Support Box and go ahead and mounting bracket that came from the ceiling fan box ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deep metal box cannot be used directly under a joist.

Whatever box you use should have its outer edge flush with the ceiling, or close to flush. The original plastic fan box which straddled the ceiling joist would have worked if the hardware for the new fixture had a metal mounting strap which could be secured into the ceiling joist through the slots used for the two long fan bracket screws.

The second plastic box (already installed) should work, but you would have to use a metal mounting strip (should be in hardware for light fixture) and use screws into the joist through the slots.

In original construction when only a standard light-weight fixture is to be installed, the box for the light is usually installed *next to* or between ceiling joists, but a basic installation of a fan box is a special fan box installed under (straddling) a joist. The boxes are different because of that, but you can adapt a fan box to hold a standard light fixture.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use what's called a "pancake box." It's a thinner version of the round metal box that you already bought. You can screw the pancake box directly into the wood joist, run the electrical wires into the pancake box and then install the fan right below the pancake box. You won't need any other parts.

In addition to being cheaper and simpler, a pancake box should give you a better look because your fan will be flush with the ceiling, or close to it.

Comment: It **must** be a box rated for a ceiling fan. These require a much higher toughness rating because they are subject to intense vibration.  A lesser box will simply crack or work-harden the fasteners or ears until they break.

Answer (score 2):

> maybe should I just... leave the Fan Master Jr. Support Box...?

Yes, if the new plastic box in your picture is listed as a fan support box, than that is all you need. You don't need the additional metal box hanging down below the ceiling.

What you *do* **need** to do is ensure that the fan/box is(are) supported properly by being securely screwed into the wood ceiling joist. To do this you may need a crossbar and/or extra long screws or something. Carefully read the instructions that came with the fan and the plastic fan-rated electrical box, either/both should have guidance on how to properly support the assembly.