# What sort of ceiling fan support do I need where I can't find framing?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

As I have already worked on 4 out of 5 ceiling fans I have put up so far ([previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/143679/putting-up-my-new-ceiling-fan-into-light-fixture)). Now I am going to put the last one up. I need your help on this one.

However, one of them I had a light fixuture hanging on the ceiling wall that looks like this:

[image]

So when I took this light fixture out and look at the ceiling wall to see what  is inside and here is what I found:

[image]

The one I have look much like this which has slides:

[image]

But the problem is it is  very wide and when I put my hand in the hold to find the nearest wood and there is no wood there.

My question here is do I need to replace with the different ceiling fan support box with brace kit I bought from Home Depot a few weeks ago ? This one is different than the one above and it is heavy.

[image]

Should I replace the old brace with the slides with the new one or should I just leave it and put it up?

Comment: I do not have magic CSI embiggenment powers, man -- I'll need a better photo of the inside of the box to see if it's the proper box or not!

Comment: The bar that's there now doesn't appear robust enough to support a fan. I'd replace it.

Comment: @isherwood  - Thanks for answer and yeah that is what I am afraid of because my gut feeling tells me to do that... That means I have to go up the attic and check if I need to add a wood and put it a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted everyone to know that we hired somebody and told us that it is not possible to put up the ceiling fan. We decided to return the light fixture back .

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer this! Of course, "not possible" is only related to the amount of money you're willing to spend and the time you're willing to spend on it... _Somewhere_ up there is enough wood to support your ceiling fan! However, I can see with that angled ceiling that there might be enough slope that the fan would have to hang too low to miss the ceiling. Please be sure to check-mark your answer, so others know that this does have an "accepted" one.

Comment: Certainly ! It always to know if this works or not...I was not confident doing it so I had someone came and told me that the equipment is too thin and to long to hang a ceiling fan.  Always have a second brain to double check.

Comment: If you'd really like to get a ceiling fan in here, contact a _different_ electrician and ask if he can _replace_ the existing box with a fan rated box, and if so, can he do it _without_ tearing up the ceiling. Some may be more willing to put in some extra effort than others. You'll pay more, of course, but if that's really what you want, it may be worth it to you. (Of course, the extra money may make it _not_ so worth it, but you won't know if you don't ask.)