# Part 2 - What sort of ceiling fan support do I need where I can't find framing?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, ceiling-fan, junction-box

I am return and resume  to work on my ceiling fan in the dining room. Last August of 2018, I tried to put it up but the support bar is different than others. I did not know what to do until I saw a poster from a company that they took picture fan fixture boxes. I was looking at it and realized that there is something I was missing.. a bracket strap to hold the support bar.

[What sort of ceiling fan support do I need where I can't find framing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145318/what-sort-of-ceiling-fan-support-do-i-need-where-i-cant-find-framing)

I went to Lowe's and found the ceiling box with this :

https://www.lowes.com/pd/CARLON-Ceiling-Box-with-Adjustable-Bar-Hanger/3152573

but I had a problem is that it is wobble and the nuts I drilled in is stuck.

Do you have any suggest to fix this problem ?

[image]

What options do I have ?

Answer (score 1):

The box you used is for a light fixture and is designed to be installed during construction before the drywall is installed. It is not designed for a fan, and even for a light it *cannot* be installed with the ceiling drywall already in place.

You need to get one that is listed as *retrofit* for a fan, e.g., [Home Depot ceiling fan retrofit](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-15-5-cu-in-Retrofit-Ceiling-Fan-Saf-T-Brace-0110000/204845572?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD27E%7C27-6_CONDUIT-BOXES-FITTINGS%7CNA%7CPLA%7C71700000034238990%7C58700003946879308%7C92700031954573778&gclid=Cj0KCQjwoInnBRDDARIsANBVyAS9BTroavEoeg0Z8WxriOhpMX8ddCQDxHuwFsAYZEaLKrDUzVuHI8kaAo1rEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) The retrofit ceiling fan support allows one to expand the support against the ceiling joists by rotating the bar, then the box is fastened to the bar. See the video on the link.

Answer (score 0):

... I didn't check your link first... the adjustable one you linked isn't rated for rotation. That is what differs between boxes... and to clean this long message up because I'm tired and rambling. I can't tell if the box you have in the wall has an adjustable bar. I have to assume its screwed into a board that runs joist to joist. And that that board has at least 2 screws on each end

1. First option. Cut drywall in a square, keeping drywall intact. Replace/relocate existing items. Remount drywall.
2. Make those screws come off and remount a shallow box, assuming your fan is light enough.
3. Use something like a dremel to shave down the lip of the box, not the screw holes do to structural support. (The screws need a certain depth to anchor well)

Directions for DIY 2x4 fan brace:

You need:

-2x4 to span the distance between the joists
-six 3 inch nails or screws for "toe nailing"
-the new work cieling fan fixture box
-roughly six 1 inch nails or screws to fit the holes of the new work box (or however many it takes)
-possibly a razor knife to cut insulation
-drill, bit for screws if using screws, and drill bit for pilot holes

Steps:
1. Cut insulation and separate it above the hole.
2.  Pre-fit 2x4 to make sure it fits snugly, not not to tight.
3. Drill 2 pilot holes at both ends of 2x4 at 45⁰ angle and a 3rd hole on the opposite side between those so you have 3 holes at either end, 6 total.
4. Seat 2x4 flush on top of drywall beside existing hole.
5. Screw in 3 inch screws.
6. Seat new work box against the 2x4 and in the ceiling hole. So its flush against the 2x4.
7. Put in 1 inch screws.
8. Put wires back through box.
9. Mount fan

Comment: Sorry the link I added was long but I am not expert on this one.. I had a luck with others 4 of them because it was easy to do...  This one was hard for me.. Not sure if I should do it or hire someone who can fix it... The problem is the attic I have has a lot of fibers all over ...

Comment: If you can access it from the attic, you can easily do this yourself. However, if you don't feel comfortable, then hire somebody. It would probably a 30 minute job or less.

Comment: who do I call for ? What is their job title so I can look for one

Comment: Look up "handyman in my area" or call lowes to see what they would charge. Our Lowes here had handymen for windows and odd jobs.

Comment: Look back at original post. I added a quick DIY instructions.